# applying gravity breaks entirely this AI movement code

Tags: movement, ai, godot, kinematic, gravity

I'm calling this function every 0.078 seconds so about at 13 fps using a timer connected to `_ready()`

this way my game can easily run over 400 enemy units with little to no impact on performance because this way the physcis of the players can run at a normal rate and only enemies are stuck at lower fps, only problem is..... gravity.

applying gravity related in any shape, way or form either direclty in the timer or within `_physics_process(delta)`  or in any other way just breaks the code and the enemies are being pushed to the side when they are idle.

```
var Speed = 10
var rotationSpeed = 10
var stoppingDistance = 2.5
var chaseTimer
var gravity = 20
var direction: Vector3
var velocity: Vector3

func _ready():
chaseTimer = Timer.new()
add_child(chaseTimer)
chaseTimer.wait_time = 0.078
chaseTimer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_Timer_timeout")
chaseTimer.start()

func _on_Timer_timeout():
    Chase(get_process_delta_time())


   func Chase(delta):
    var players = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Player")
    if players.size() > 0:
        var target = players[0]
        var minDistance = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(target.global_transform.origin)
    for player in players:
        var distance = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(player.global_transform.origin)
        if distance < minDistance:
            minDistance = distance
            target = player

    direction = (target.global_transform.origin - self.global_transform.origin).normalized()
    var targetRotation = -atan2(direction.z, direction.x)

    var currentRotation = self.rotation.y
    var deltaRotation = targetRotation - currentRotation

    if abs(deltaRotation) > 3.14159:
        if deltaRotation > 0:
            deltaRotation -= 2 * 3.14159
        else:
            deltaRotation += 2 * 3.14159

    var rotationStep = rotationSpeed * delta

    if abs(rotationStep) > abs(deltaRotation):
        rotationStep = deltaRotation

    var distanceToTarget = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(target.global_transform.origin)
    if distanceToTarget > stoppingDistance and distanceToTarget <= 15:
        self.rotation.y += rotationStep
        velocity = Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z) * Speed
        move_and_slide(velocity)
```

**Edit:**

My initial plan was to not use the `_physics_process` at all, that's why im using an artificial fixed refresh rate of 13 fps for the enemies.

I thought the problem was my code.... I was mistaken, the problem is the sheer amount of enemies.

I changed the collision shapes of the enemies to squares because it's the simplest shape and this seemes to have helped.

now when gravity is applied the scene can have up to 128 enemies before things start breaking...

before with the normal capsule collision shape after only 46 enemies things started to break.

it seems the problem really is just godot, the game engine can't hold all these calculations, even tho the enemy is running at 13 fps.

for now let's call it a day and I'll make sure to delete all enemies if players aren't arround and make some spawning zones with a limit of 128, this way a server/game doesn't blow up

**Edit 2**

I probably fixed it, by making all enemy entities spawn way up in the air, this probably did something to the physics engine to warm it up or something like that and after this only a small portion of enemies were pushed away by gravity.

then apparently making all enemy nodes that are too far away from the player be invisible and paused solved entirely the problem, at least it seems, 380 enemies and no performance issues... even tho I had to set the fps limit to 20 for the player, otherwise the low fps movement of the enemies result in trails of afterimages being left behind the enemies.

gonna see if adding animations will cause further problems or not, but animations shouldn't use any calculations from the engine so I'm crossing my fingers.

[image]

**Edit 3:**

it worked quite well, so I could delete all area nodes and just use the global position of anything belonging in the group player, this is compatible with both multiplayer and with my save system and also thanks to @[Theraot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/10408/theraot) for his posts on _process() vs _physics_process() which taught me a good lesson on how to not use either of them when dealing with hundreds of entities lol :)

around 90 Archers, animated, with chase/attack/flee/walk_randomly and idle states and they run decently

[Archer.gd on github if anyone needs it](https://github.com/Ceisri/Godot-Action-Combat/blob/main/Creatures/Enemies/mob%20archer/Archer.gd)

[image]

Comment: Do your enemies actually need physics/ gravity ?

Comment: it's a 3d game....if say the enemy is following a player and the player jumps off a cliff to excape or if terrain is uneven, the enemy will just float above the player's head

Comment: It highly depends. Some games don't let enemies follow you when you jump over cliffs. Uneven terrain can be as well solved without gravity but just a raycast.

Comment: @Zibelas That would require an extra node, an extra check for collision...more calculations for the same thing